# No default VM network adapter after migrating to vNetwork Distributed Switch (VMware vSphere 4.1)

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I've set up a datacenter in vSphere 4.1 with one distributed switch for all VM networking and one regular switch on each host used strictly for management. No VM port group exists on the local switches.

Ever since removing the last local port group, when I create a new virtual machine in "Typical" mode I end up with no network adapter. Before removing that port group it would always create a default network adapter on the "VM Network" port group. Everything is fine in "Custom" mode as it shows a drop-down for choosing a network and defaults to the right VDS port group, but in Typical mode it just doesn't create a network device.

How can I set the default VM Network so that VMs are not created without a network device?

Comment: No answer of hand, have you read through http://vmware.com/files/pdf/vsphere-vnetwork-ds-migration-configuration-wp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual switch for virtual machine on the hosts even not connected to any network card. It would do the trick.